# Binding multiple objects in Grails

Tags: grails

I have there domain classes:

- Person. (Person.ID, Name,Address)
- Designation.(Designation.ID, Title, Band)
- SalarySlip (Person.ID, Designation.ID, totalIncome, Tax etc etc.)

In the update method the person controller when I assign a person a designation from a list of designation values I want to insert a new record inside SalarySlip.

Something like:

```
def update = {
   def SalarySlipInstance = new SalarySlip()
   SalarySlipInstance.Person.ID = Params.ID //is this correct?
   SalarySlipInstance.Designation.ID = ?? //since the value is coming from a list. How can I bind this field?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the Person and Designation objects first:

```
salarySlipInstance.Person = Person.get(params.person.id)
salarySlipInstance.Designation = Designation.get(params.designation.id)
```

If in your form you prefix the person and designation id's with person. and designation. it makes it easier to load.

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thanks for your reply, I tried your solution but I am getting the following error:

Cannot set property 'id' on null object

Comment: the left hand side is wrong, try these:      

salarySlipInstance.Person = Person.get(params.person.id)
salarySlipInstance.Designation = Designation.get(params.designation.id)

Comment: I wrote this 

def SalarySlipInstance = new SalarySlip()    
SalarySlipInstance.person= Person.get(params.person.id)     
SalarySlipInstance.designation = Designation.get(params.designation .id)      
SalarySlipInstance.save()   

The update method works fine, however, when I check the data using dbPlugin, there is no data in the table!

Am i missing anything here,

Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, rectified now. If it's not saved check the object binding errors (salarySlipInstance.hasErrors() salarySlipInstance.errors)